# How can I predict the next result?

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I've been playing around with Azure ML for å couple of days... but I can't seem to get to a point with the right algorithms to predict the *next value* in a sorted list.

In Excel I made this simple list of 2000 points:

```
ITERATION,DATA,LABEL
1,1,SMALLER
2,2,SMALLER
3,3,BIGGER
4,4,BIGGER
5,5,BIGGER
6,6,BIGGER
7,7,BIGGER
8,1,SMALLER
9,2,SMALLER
10,3,BIGGER
11,4,BIGGER
12,5,BIGGER
13,6,BIGGER
14,7,BIGGER
...
```

Where label is defined as

```
If ITERATION < 500 then LABEL < 3 = "SMALLER", else "BIGGER"
If ITERATION < 1000 then LABEL < 4 = "SMALLER", else "BIGGER"
If ITERATION < 1500 then LABEL < 5 = "SMALLER", else "BIGGER"
If ITERATION < 2000 then LABEL < 6 = "SMALLER", else "BIGGER"
```

I've got a decent prediction and published a web service, but the service wants the input ITERATION and DATA to "predict" LABEL.

Is there a way I can train the model and at "runtime" pass in a data series and get the predicted next value?

Comment: This question is a bit broad and it looks like you are missing some ML-basics. Without assumptions about your data, there is no algorithm who can predict better than random-guessing. So you need to introduce some assumptions (somehow). From this short description it looks more like time-series prediction or extrapolation, but this is of course a model-decision taken (which is introducing some assumptions when these are made more detailed / usable; example: linear extrapolation vs. cubic extrapolation).

Comment: @sascha I thought 2000 data points could make the trick... the 14 elements in the list is just a cutout.

Comment: It's a supervised binary classification problem where ITERATION and DATA are the explanatory variables, so you need them for prediction of the LABEL.